# Go module installation error "undefined: any"

Tags: go

I got the following error. Could anybody try the same command? I want to know whether it is a bug in the package or it is related to the version of go that I use or my setup.

```
$ go get github.com/gonejack/webarchive-to-html
# github.com/alecthomas/kong
../../../go/src/github.com/alecthomas/kong/callbacks.go:105:65: undefined: any
../../../go/src/github.com/alecthomas/kong/callbacks.go:124:15: undefined: any
../../../go/src/github.com/alecthomas/kong/context.go:723:27: undefined: any
../../../go/src/github.com/alecthomas/kong/options.go:59:8: undefined: any
../../../go/src/github.com/alecthomas/kong/options.go:66:18: undefined: any
$ echo $?
2
$ go version
go version go1.16 darwin/amd64
```

Comment: Fix by installing Go 1.18 or later.

Comment: Go1.16 is no longer supported. Always check with the latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see [go.mod](https://github.com/gonejack/webarchive-to-html/blob/main/go.mod) file of the package you trying to get. The package is written down based on 1.18 version of golang. So you need at least 1.18 version.

```golang
module github.com/gonejack/webarchive-to-html

go 1.18

...
```

Built-in type `any` is introduced in go 1.18. `any` is a simple alias for interface{}.

```golang
// builtin.go
type any = interface{}
```